# How can I scrape inline css?

Tags: php, scrape

I am using simple_html_dom script for getting information from a site.

I am trying to **scrape** an element that carrying the display: none property.

Here's the element:

```
<label data-product-attribute-value="1307" class="form-label" for="attribute_1307" style="display: none;">This is the title</label>
```

How can I identify that this tag carries inline CSS display: none;?

Here's my code:

```
$html  = get_html_data($url);
foreach ($html->find('.form-label') as $links) {
   echo $links->outertext;
}
```

`$links->outertext` is giving me only this:

```
<label data-product-attribute-value="1307" class="form-label" for="attribute_1307">This is the title</label>
```

You can see that, it's not including the style property while scraping.

So how can I get the inline CSS property? If I have to use a different library, please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

You can get `style` using `->style`. Try this:

```
foreach ($html->find('.form-label') as $links) {
   echo ($links->style); //op : display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doable for me as expected:

```
<?php
$html = <<< HTML
<label data-product-attribute-value="1307" class="form-label" for="attribute_1307" style="display: none;">
This is the title
</label>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
echo (   $label->hasAttribute('style')
      && preg_match('/display:\s*none/', $label->getAttribute('style')) ) ?
    "display set to 'none'" : "display NOT set to 'none'";
```

The output obviously is:

```
display set to 'none'
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I found out that file_get_html not getting the style property for that specific Label either. I am getting style property for few element, but not for all. I also use curl to scrap all the HTML through URL, but the same issue coming. Please suggest.